# Subsite access without being a member of the subsite in wp multisite network

Tags: multisite, users, capabilities, user-access, multisite-user-management

How can a user access a subsite without being the member of that subsite in a wp multisite network?

What I understand is that a user can not access a private post in a subsite if he is not the member of that subsite but I want to remove this restrictions.

I tried to use the method `add_user_to_blog` but it is not what I am looking for.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you want all users to access the site, including private posts, why have a private post?

Comment: I do only want people with specific roles to access those posts. For that reason a user must login first. So what I want is that a user login to main site and then be able to access subsites without being member of those subsites.

Comment: Multisite should allow users to access all sites, unless specifically prevented via a plugin or code. A quick search shows this article might be useful: https://wpengine.com/resources/wordpress-multisite-user-management/